# using c++ rest sdk get information

Tags: c++, rest

I'm studying c++ and I'd want to get information using rest api. I searched internet and found there's library about this, rest sdk(casablanca). I read several posts, and a tutorial. then I wrote this code

```
auto fileStream = std::make_shared<ostream>();
pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results.html")).then([=](ostream outFile){
*fileStream = outFile;

// Create http_client to send the request.
http_client client(U("http://www.kobis.or.kr/"));

// Build request URI and start the request.
uri_builder builder(U("/kobisopenapi/webservice/rest/code/searchDailyBoxOffice.json"));
builder.append_query (U("key"), U("770f0e38d783ce5478e1e618c53d9452")); 
builder.append_query(U("targetDt"), U("20161125"));

std::wcout << builder.to_string() << std::endl;
return client.request(methods::GET, builder.to_string());})
// Handle response headers arriving.

.then([=](http_response response){
printf("Received response status code:%u\n", response.status_code());

// Write response body into the file.
return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
})
// Close the file stream.
.then([=](size_t){
return fileStream->close();
});
// Wait for all the outstanding I/O to complete and handle any exceptions
```

After Executing this code, in the result.html, there is an message "key is wrong". but the key isn't wrong. where did I wrong? Please help me!

The url should be like this:
http://www.kobis.or.kr/kobisopenapi/webservice/rest/boxoffice/searchDailyBoxOfficeList.json?key=430156241533f1d058c603178cc3ca0e&targetDt=20120101

Comment: key and targetDt in your code and in your given uri is different

Comment: Yes, I know that. The given url is from tutorial in that site and the key and tartgetDt is my assigned key, and date I want to search. I just write url because I wanted to say the format should be like that.

Comment: Note that your code request the url /kobisopenapi/webservice/rest/ **code** /searchDailyBoxOffice.json but the example show kobisopenapi/webservice/rest/ **boxoffice** /searchDailyBoxOfficeList.json

Comment: Oh thank you so much! Why didn't I find it! Have a nice day!